# Check if type T has any overloads of a member function, SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

Consider the following, I want to check if the types I pass off to some other function `sf` has a member function `T::mf` that is required by `sf`, I know the return type and the name but there can by any number of overloads.

After some tinkering (well it is fun..) and googling , I can get something like the code below to work, the problem is that I don't know how to express that `print` can have a variable number of arguments.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>


template <typename T,typename = void>
struct has_write : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_write<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().write())> : std::true_type {};


template <typename T, typename R = void , typename ...Args>
struct has_print : std::false_type {};

// cant deduce, specialization never used
template <typename T, typename ...Args>
struct has_print<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().print(std::declval<Args>()...))> : std::true_type {};


struct Foo {
    void write();
};

struct Bar {
    int print(int, float, int);
};

int main(){
    static_assert(has_write<Foo>::value, "Does not have write..");
    static_assert(has_print<Bar>::value, "Does not have print..");
    return 0;
}
```

The above compiles with `g++` but the second `assert` fails, `clang` is a bit more helpful and tells me that the specializations for `has_print` will never be used because it cannot deduce all the types.

Comment: AFAIK the only way of doing this is to try to call `print` with 0..N instances of a type that is implicitly convertible to anything. Reflection should make this easier in the future...

Comment: Well, since your `sf` function would call a specific version of `print` with a specific number of arguments known to that function, you can check for specific `has_print` with known types.

Comment: I considered that, but I am new to this and for the sake of learning wanted to know a clean way of  (pretending this is not a xy problem) finding whether a type has any overloads.

Answer (score 2):

Since you will be calling your overload from within `sf` function, you should check for availability of the particular overload using the types `sf` function would call it with.

General checking for availability of **any** overload within a class would always be an XY problem by definition, because availability of **any** overload is never important. You need to know you can call a name with given set of arguments. Consider this: asking for availability of any overload of a given name is conceptually the same as asking if particular class has **any** method at all. And obviously you would not be interested in it?